# Mocking an external library component in React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I recently started using React Testing Library and am really confused as to how I can test external library components like an example component `SomeComponent` from `material-ui`. `SomeComponent` is just for example.

I read that React Testing Library is mainly targeted at testing the end output of the DOM but I want to check the props that are sent to the `SomeComponent` component as the props are calculated based on a user interaction. Ideally I would not want to know all the implementation details and the DOM that the `SomeComponent` component brings in as it might have been tested by `material-ui`. I just want to check if the external library component is receiving the necessary props that my component sends in.

There should be a way to test these kind of scenarios. I can check the DOM tree and check for the respective selector and check the child elements but I would ideally want to just check the props. I saw at places where people mention that `react-testing-library` is aimed at avoiding testing the implementation details of a component.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';

import { SomeComponent } from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(props.data);

  const handleFilter = (e) => {
    const filterType = e.target.id;

    setData(
      props.data.filter(item => item.type === filterType)
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="movies" onClick={handleFilter}>Movies</div>
      <div id="shows" onClick={handleFilter}>Shows</div>
      <div id="anime" onClick={handleFilter}>Anime</div>
      <SomeComponent 
        data={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

import { SomeComponent } from "@material-ui/core";

test("allows users to add items to their list", () => {

  // Confused as to how to mock SomeComponent
  // jest.mock('') ?

  const data = [
    { id: 1, type: 'anime', title: 'One Piece' }, 
    { id: 2, type: 'movies', title: 'The Matrix Resurrections' }
  ];

  const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<App data={data} />);

  const input = getByLabelText("What needs to be done?");
  const button = getByText("Add #1");

  // Filter Anime
  const animeButton = getByLabelText("Anime");
  fireEvent.click(animeButton);

  const filteredData = [{ id: 1, type: 'anime', title: 'One Piece' }];

  expect(SomeComponent).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
    data: filteredData
  }));

});
```

The above test fails mentioning that `SomeComponent` is expected to be a `mock` or a `spy`.

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

Comment: Rather than testing the props passed to a component (an implementation detail), you should focus on testing what is visible on the DOM if those props are passed to it.

Comment: @juliomalves I agree about visible DOM for an internal component but why would I want to test the external library component rendering? All I should be concerned is to send the necessary props to the external component, shouldn't that be the main focus of my unit tests?